# Safari 11 - White space in CSS animation

Tags: css, animation, safari, transform

When resizing the browser, there are white spaces in Safari 11.

```css
.river {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; 
  position: relative;
}

.river-frame {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  animation: river-horizontal 10s infinite linear;
}

.river-frame:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 500%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-size: 20% 100%;
  background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff);
}

.river-frame-img {
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes river-horizontal {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="river">
  <div class="river-frame">
    <img class="river-frame-img" src="https://image.ibb.co/iUbhYw/library.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

We can't find the source of issue, any help is appreciated. Consider that we only want to use transform in our animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A force redraw is needed for Safari browsers. There is a trick that can be done using jQuery. Include jQuery in your document. And run this small script and things will be working as expected. I have included the snippet below. Hope it helps.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('.river').hide().show(0);
})
```

```css
.river {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.river-frame {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  animation: river-horizontal 10s infinite linear;
}

.river-frame:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 500%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-size: 20% 100%;
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/iUbhYw/library.jpg);
}

.river-frame-img {
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes river-horizontal {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="river">
  <div class="river-frame">
    <img class="river-frame-img" src="https://image.ibb.co/iUbhYw/library.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

.

Comment: This issue is happeing after update in Safari 11, before that it was working fine. Maybe they fix this issue later. For now, we are fine. Thanks